# How can I turn a dataframe into a string and still keep all the rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following little script that gets about 100 rows of data from a database, puts it into a Data Frame, and then turns the Data Frame into a string:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import text
import pandas as pd
import Inspector as spec

connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=data_governor;DATABASE=ProcessingInspector;UID=xyz;PWD=123"
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

# get data from database
qry = text("EXECUTE dbo.InspectionServiceData")
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # turn the DF into a string
    query_result = df.to_string(header=True, index=False)

    # get all the rows
    rows = [[field.strip() for field in line.split('  ') if field] for line in query_result.splitlines()[2:-1]]

    # send rows to 3rd party script
    for inspection in spec.process_data(rows):
        # testing
        print(inspection)
```

I am using a 3rd party Python script that transforms each row of the data and inspects it , inputs each row into a template file, and then emails me a report.

So in order to send the rows, I turned my Data Frame into a string and then pass in the collection of rows into their Python script.

I am getting the error below, and after contacting the 3rd party tech support, I found out that it's expecting multiple rows, but I am only sending one giant one.

I think it has to do with turning the data frame into a string.  I think that converts all the rows into one big giant row.

Is there a way I can convert my data frame to a string, but still keep all the rows?

Thanks!

```
    # Error from system: Expected multiple rows, only found one.
```

Comment: Probably not. It depends on what the third party script expects as input and if it can be configured or modified to send the email in a different format.

Comment: We'd need to know the details of the third party script to answer this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the entire DataFrame to a string, use the .iterrows() method to iterate through the rows of the DataFrame. For each row, we can convert the fields to strings, strip any whitespace, and then pass that row as a list to the spec.process_data() function.
Try this:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # iterate through the DataFrame rows and process each row
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        row_data = [str(field).strip() for field in row]
        inspections = spec.process_data([row_data])
        
        # testing
        for inspection in inspections:
            print(inspection)
```